# Screen Scraping of aspx page using curl

Tags: php, asp.net, curl, screen-scraping

I am using this code, and its not working. Please help

```
$url = "http://www.riogrande.com/Category/Findings-and-Finished-Jewelry/132/Bails-and-Enhancers/472";
$file=file_get_contents($url);
preg_match("#.*?#mis", $file, $arr_viewstate);
$viewstate = urlencode($arr_viewstate[1]);
$eventvalidation = urlencode($arr_viewstate[2]);
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, // return web page
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false, // don't return headers
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", // handle all encodings
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; en-US; rv:1.8.1.7) Gecko/20070914 Firefox/2.0.0.7'", // who am i
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true, // set referer on redirect
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120, // timeout on connect
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 1120, // timeout on response
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, // stop after 10 redirects
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '__EVENTTARGET='.urlencode('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderBody$SearchPageNavigationTop$rptPager$ctl01').'&__EVENTARGUMENT='.urlencode('').'&__VIEWSTATE='.$viewstate.'&__EVENTVALIDATION='.$eventvalidation.'&__LASTFOCUS='.urlencode('')
);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"?  Is it throwing an error?  What is it supposed to do?  You're not giving us enough to go on.

Comment: It starts with reading tutorials and learning programming, not dropping a pile of code here and add quotation marks. Please see ask-advice which you must have gone through before posting the question.

Comment: Also please properly format and indent your code, others need to read it.

Comment: You code says nothing about what you cant to achieve ..

Comment: sorry for incomplete information. On given url, there is paging. I can scrap first page but can't next one. I use this code for 2nd page, because "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderBody$SearchPageNavigationTop$rptPager$ctl01" value is passed to __doPostBack function when we click on page 2. So its not giving page 2 content. i am using this value for                                                                   preg_match("#<input.*?name=\"__viewstate\".*?value=\"(.*?)\".*?>.*?<input.*?name=\"__eventvalidation\".*?value=\"(.*?)\".*?>#mis", $file, $arr_viewstate);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The truth is that i don't understand what you want to achieve but i definitely know that that is not the way to get `__VIEWSTATE` and `__EVENTVALIDATION`

it should be something like this

```
$url = "http://www.riogrande.com/Category/Findings-and-Finished-Jewelry/132/Bails-and-Enhancers/472";
$html = file_get_contents($url);

preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.*?)" />~',$html,$viewstate);
preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="(.*?)" />~',$html,$eventvalidation);

$viewstate = $viewstate[1];
$eventvalidation = $eventvalidation[1] ;

var_dump($viewstate,$eventvalidation);
```

Comment: i use this but giving error page.

Comment: i am using                                                 preg_match("#<input.*?name=\"__viewstate\".*?value=\"(.*?)\".*?>.*?<input.*?name=\"__eventvalidation\".*?value=\"(.*?)\".*?>#mis", $file, $arr_viewstate);

Comment: Works perfectly http://codepad.viper-7.com/CTSevY

Comment: i add this code and it showing a string of long length and after that it gives object moved to here. error page. There is no content of page 2 that i need.

Answer (score 0):

This code appears to be working... pasting that code into a blank php file, I get the contents of the target URL. However, images are broken, stylesheets are not pulled, javascript doesn't work.

The problem with scraping an entire webpage like that, especially one that uses relative URLs, the images, CSS, JavaScript, etc. won't work as intended.

If you insist on scraping a page and spitting out the results, try replacing the last couple lines of code to be like this:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

$result = str_replace("../../../../","http://www.riogrande.com/",$result);
echo $result;
```

I just happened to notice that the relative URLs started with `../../../../` so making them absolute URLs may help load the images correctly.

Comment: yes its giving content of 1st page. I use this for 2nd page. any help